# New Function.... Not working randomly enough

Tags: python, list, function, random

```
import random

####################
def ListRearrange(listx):
    listz = listx[:]
     x = len(listx)
     for y in range(x):
               a = random.choice(range(x))
               b = listx.pop(a)
               listx.append(b)

     return listx
####################
list1 = ["Hello", 5000, "60", "Timmothy", 400, "2", "Okay"]
print list1
for g in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9):         
     p = ListRearrange(list1)
     print p
```

Thanks to whoever looks at this. What I am trying to do is create a randomly jumbled list. However when I run it, it doesn't seem very random at all. It is possible I am overlooking something, or that is just as random as it gets. Please get back to me when you have a chance.

Answer (score 4):

Your shuffle isn’t a fair one. It moves a random item in the list to the end of the list as many times as there are items in the list, but that means the first item only has a slightly less than 1 − ((n − 1) / n)<sup>n</sup> chance of being moved, where in a fair shuffle it would have a (n − 1) / n chance of being moved. For a list of 7 elements, that’s about a 34% chance for the first element to stay in the same place, compared to about a 14% chance in a fair shuffle.

Use a simple, standard shuffle, like [Fisher–Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
def ListRearrange(l):
    result = l[:]

    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        swap = random.randrange(i, len(l))
        result[i], result[swap] = result[swap], result[i]

    return result
```

Or the built-in [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

Comment: My Lord I am an idiot. 
    random.shuffle
Wow. Thank you.